# mysql triggers on multiple instances

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger which works after insert|update on one table(suppose table 1). The trigger insert & updates data on other tables(table 2 & 3).

But as the trigger does its insertion and updates the initial table(table 1) gets another data inserted. In that case will that data will be missed by the trigger or it will execute after finishing its engaged data on table 1?

if the trigger misses the data then what should I do?
if the trigger works for all the entry then it may run all the time and the time will increase along with the data. Will that effect the speed of the database server?

can I run same thread on multiple instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no data lost in any case.

If the traffic is very high to the table1 then it will effect on the database server performance.